# Problem calling a simple C# Webservice method from Postman

Tags: c#, web-services, postman

I created a really simple webservice using C#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Receival
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    
    public class ReceiveService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string Mirror(string request)
        {
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Postman to test.

The HelloWorld() works OK

The Mirror() returns error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:
> text/plain.    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
> at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

whatever the ContentType I use in the PostMan Request header

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The default content-type is `text/xml`. Have you tried to use that?

Comment: If you need to change that to for example `application/json` then you can use `[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json]`

Comment: Thank you Peter Csala. But where should I put that in my code?

Comment: Here is a [related MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview)

Comment: I use asmx though :(

Comment: In that case `ScriptMethodAttribute` can be your friend. `[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Answer (score 1):

'Request' is a .Net object - convert to a string type like text/json/html before returning.

Comment: I cannot determine in which event of the webservice, the Request pops in so I can manipulate it :(

Comment: Try replacing 'return request;' with 'return request.ToString()', for example.